# Odd graphics issue on Kubuntu

Tags: error, graphics

Since moving to Kubuntu 20.04 I have been getting this strange visual tearing in emacs (running in its own window). I find that as I move the point along the line with the tearing, it is corrected. Has anyone experienced this or similar issues?

[image: weird graphics issue]

Some system info:

```
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-59-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-4690K CPU @ 3.50GHz
Memory: 15.6 GiB of RAM

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950]
```

Comment: What is the question? If you think you've discovered a bug, consider reporting it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Good point - edited to include a question.

Comment: A question asking whether anyone has seen this isn't a great question for this site, which is mainly for specific how-to Q&A. This isn't the place to report something that you suspect might be an issue/bug. I suggest that you file a bug -- the Emacs developers will investigate and determine whether it's actually a bug, and if not they'll explain to you why they think it isn't etc.